# Bypass SoundCloud API's SCLoginViewController and instead use openURL

Tags: ios, oauth, soundcloud

Fellow SoundCloud API/SDK devs,

It seems that the SoundCloud iOS SDK is a little long in the tooth, namely SCLoginViewController.  It's clearly in need of updating and has cosmetic issues when it appears.

Instead, I'm looking at simply using openURL on the URL that the SC prepares:

```
[SCSoundCloud requestAccessWithPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler:^(NSURL* preparedURL) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:preparedURL];
}];
```

and then catching the result my iOS app's handleURL call (as the URL comes back as

```
myapp://oauth?code=0a83...
```

So my question to the SC API dev is: how I get from having that `NSURL` in hand to `[SCSoundCloud account]` returning the appropriate account.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a deep dive into the bowels of OAuth2Client (https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client), I have the answer...

The first step of a typical oauth flow is a GET with a param that specifies a redirect URL.  Once the user authenticates from this initial GET, the host redirects to the specified URL with an additional  URL param, `code`.  On iOS, this typically takes the form of `myapp://oauth&code=ZZZZ`.

At this point, the app extracts the code and and uses it as a param for a subsequent POST request that then returns the oauth access token (`access_token`).  Using OAuth2Client's flow, when your app gets the URL `myapp://oauth&code=ZZZZ` via UIApplicationDelegate's `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:(id)`, you need subsequently call:

```
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] handleRedirectURL:inURL];
```

This will get OAuth2Client to pull off the `code` param, form the new POST URL and arguments, internally perform the POST, process the response (digging out `access_token` etc), and then send the notification `NXOAuth2AccountDidChangeAccessTokenNotification`.

In the SoundCloud iOS SDK, their `SCLoginViewController` captures that `myapp://oauth&code=ZZZZ` step, so that's why you never see that step.

Comment: I'm confused - did you wind up being able to bypass the SCLoginViewController?

Comment: yes, fully.   all out oauth stuff is homegrown and work great EXCEPT for an issue out of our hands: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497785/handle-popups-tabs-in-sfsafariviewcontroller?noredirect=1#comment71410949_39497785

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble using the SoundCloud SDK with all its dependencies. Instead of using `SCSoundCloud requestAccessWithPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler`, I want to prepare the URL myself (in addition to using openURL instead of the SDK method).

How exactly is the URL prepared? Ie what does the URL that opens SoundCloud look like?